# How do I solve\debug AOT build errors Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

**UPDATE**

I have moved down Xamarin versions to 4.4 from 4.5 and the AOT issues has gone. We do we still want to be able to upgrade though so it would be useful to know how to solve this issue

Windows dev machine

- Windows 8.1
- Xamarin iOS 10.10.0.30
- Xamarin 4.5.0.443 (see **UPDATE**)

Mac Build Machine

- Xamarin iOS 10.10

Recently upgraded Xamarin and am having AOT compilation issues

> Could not AOT the assembly
>   '/Users/[USER]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[AppName]/905548e7be511ce31e001b2858172e80/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/SQLiteNetExtensions.dll'

The build logs says

AOT Compilation exited with code 134, command:

> MONO_PATH=/Users/[UserName]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[OurAssemblyName]/905548e7be511ce31e001b2858172e80/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.33/bin/arm-darwin-mono-sgen
>   --debug -O=gsharedvt --aot=mtriple=armv7-ios,data-outfile=/Users/[UserName]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[OurAssemblyName]/905548e7be511ce31e001b2858172e80/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/armv7/SQLiteNetExtensions.aotdata.armv7,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,full,soft-debug,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/[UserName]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[OurAssemblyName]/905548e7be511ce31e001b2858172e80/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/armv7/SQLiteNetExtensions.dll.s
>   "/Users/[UserName]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[OurAssemblyName]/905548e7be511ce31e001b2858172e80/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/SQLiteNetExtensions.dll"
>
> Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly
>   /Users/[UserName]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[OurAssemblyName]/905548e7be511ce31e001b2858172e80/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/SQLiteNetExtensions.dll
>
> AOTID 22AE78C2-4B42-75BE-C8CC-80A27CDE517F
>
> Could not load signature of
>   SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.ReadOperations:GetAllWithChildren due
>   to: Could not resolve type with token 01000018 (from typeref,
>   class/assembly SQLite.Net.ISQLiteConnection, SQLite.Net,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
>   assembly:SQLite.Net, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null type:SQLite.Net.ISQLiteConnection member:
>
> Assertion at
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4691/3e5ac5ff/source/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mono/mini/mini-generic-sharing.c:3500,
>   condition `mono_error_ok (&error)' not met C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(747,3): error :
>   Could not AOT the assembly
>   '/Users/[UserName]/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/[OurAssemblyName]/905548e7be511ce31e001b2858172e80/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/SQLiteNetExtensions.dll'

How do I debug this issue?

Comment: While your project links to SQLiteNetExtensions.dll, does it also link to SQLite.NET.dll?

Comment: The only file that has a ref to SQLiteExtensions is SQLite.NEt. Our Xamarin iOS app does not reference SQLiteExtensions  directly